# Strings searches in a list, if the list contains a string with a space

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'd like to identify a word in a list, however one of the strings has a space in-between and is not recognized. My code:

```
res = [word for word in somestring if word not in myList]

myList = ["first", "second", "the third"]
```

So when

```
somestring = "test the third"
```

is parsed then `res="test the third"` (should be "`test"`).

How can I overcome strings searches in a list, if the list contains a string with a space?

Comment: I didn't understand. You say list in your question, but your example is not a list and is just a str. Is your example correct  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you can use `split()`.

```
myList = ["first", "second", "the third"]

somestring = "test the third" 

n=[x.split() for x in myList]
#[['first'], ['second'], ['the', 'third']]
```

You can flatten this by:

```
m=[item for sublist in n for item in sublist]
#['first', 'second', 'the', 'third']
```

Similarly, you can `split() somestring`

```
s=somestring.split()
#['test', 'the', 'third']
```

Finally:

```
for x in s:
  if x not in m:
    print(x)
#test
```

You can also get the result in one line; but it is not very readable:

```
[x for x in somestring.split() if x not in (item for sublist in (x.split() for x in myList) for item in sublist)]
#['test']
```

Comment: thanks for that. Actually this is almost correct. Only it doesn't take into account that the removal happens only for the combination of the two words "the third". So it shouldn't remove if the word contains "the" or "third".

Comment: @pymat sorry I didn't get that. You mean to say if myList is `["first", "second", "the"]` or `myList = ["first", "second", "third"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `myLst` as a list of patterns for regex substitution:

```
import re

myList = ["first", "second", "the third"]
somestring = "test the third"
res = re.sub(fr'({"|".join(myList)})', '', somestring).strip()
print(res)
```

---

```
test
```